# Скорость переключения SCTP-интерфейсов

Tags: сеть

Мгновенно ли переключаются sctp интерфейсы при падении одного адреса в ассоциации?

Answer (score 2):

В общем исследования показали, что не мгновенно, а в зависимости от полей spp_hbinterval, что было довольно-таки логично, но я не знал про существование heartbeat у sctp.